# Uncaught ReferenceError: hide is not defined error

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie on javascript. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap Modal.

console get me this error. why?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hide is not defined

JS

```
$('#te').modal(hide)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this (Check the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)):

```
$('#te').modal('hide');
```

Notice the quotes, you missed those, `hide` should be `'hide'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around hide.

Like this:

```
 $('#te').modal('hide')
```

Reference:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage